# Magento as API Client

Tags: customer, api, catalog, integrate

I'm planning an ERP - Magento integration.

I know that Magento has his own API that I can use it when some changes occurs in our ERP. For example,  product catalog updates, new customers, etc... that part is easy, just use Magento API in our ERP code... (please correct me if i'm wrong).

This covers ERP to Magento sync. But what happens with Magento to ERP sync?

For example, I would like that when a sell occurs Magento make a POST to my ERP API telling, what client, and which products are sold.

Another example, a customer updates his phone in magento. ¿How I can sync that change with my ERP?

Thanks.

Comment: Some ERPs have web services that you could call from Magento. You’ll need to research your particular platform’s capabilities.

Comment: Yes, my ERP have an API, but how I can call that API from Magento? using events?

Comment: You could tap into some events for synchronous calls, but also Magento has the crontab for scheduled tasks as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I want realtime if possible... when some order is placed in magento I want to notify my ERP. Then i understand that events is the way.

Comment: Be sure to consider the scaling impacts with synchronous calls in your environment, as well as fault recovery. I think a queuing system fed by events can be a good compromise between speed and reliability.

Comment: hmmm I'm a bit confused... the main problem is for example, there is only 1 unit of some product. One customer buy that product in magento, and then another customer buy that product in the physical shop (this cannot be possible, but if we don't use real sync can occurs...). How I can solve this issue? Do you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull your Magento 2 via REST APIs for specific order events.  Or see if your ERP vendor has a module for Magento 2 that can push to it.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do the ERP to Magento Sync, but I'm asking for Magento to ERP sync...